# Overlapping Div Positioning

Tags: css, layout, html

I would Like to have a banner across an image. Both the image and banner (banner-snippet) are in the same parent element so the the black banner is pushed out of view. How can I fix this.

You can see my source here:

```
<div id="slide-banner">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/GoldenGateBridge-001.jpg"/>
    <div id="slide-banner-snippet">
    </div>
</div>​
```

```css
#slide-banner {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 916px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-banner img {
    height: auto;
    width: 916px;
}

#slide-banner-snippet {
    height: 55px;
    width: 916px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uSw8S/

Comment: When you say ***across***, do you literally mean the `banner` should be superimposed over the `image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely position the element you want to float, ie:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `#slide-banner` relatively positioned and make `slide-banner-snippet` absolutely positioned and add `bottom:0;`

```css
#slide-banner {
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 350px;
    width: 916px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#slide-banner img {
    height: auto;
    width: 916px;
}

#slide-banner-snippet {
    height: 55px;
    width: 916px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uSw8S/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can just put

```
<div id="slide-banner-snippet">
    </div>
```

before

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/GoldenGateBridge-001.jpg"/>
```

Example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/anaida/uSw8S/10/)